# Name of security system

Tags: encryption

This is a security system that I would like to know the name of, here is a description:

I have heard that some people will use a separate computer for decrypting messages. When they revive a message they will put it on a thumb drive and then they will carry it to a separate computer that is not connected to the internet, they will then decrypt the message and read it.

I want to know the name so that i can learn more about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *system* doesn't really have a name. But several aspects of it do:

An "[air gap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gap_%28networking%29)" is where two devices intentionally isolated such that they can't touch, and that terminology is also used in security to describe carefully maintaining one system or network physically disconnected from another.

As far as using some storage device to transfer data between two machines, we used to call that "[sneakernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet)"; a bit of a tongue-in-cheek reference to using humans to form the critical link ferrying data on foot between machines, though the term is less popular than it used to be (probably because the *concept* is less popular than it used to be).

Comment: Adequate name would be "Airgap Sneakernet". First came across the term with using floppy disks on Xenix for data transfer. Ethernet interfaces were expensive, the 1/2" coax backbone and taps were problematic and serial cable to the back room was capable only of 9600 baud. Tar it to disks and walk it back.

Comment: Bastion host can refer to the system, as it's the intermediary between environments. According to ceh dip system can also be used, but that is british slang and not all that common

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can come up with is ['Air gap'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gap_%28networking%29).